# new() method on traits with varying parameters

Tags: rust, traits

I'm trying to make a trait with various implementations with different internal parameters:

```
pub trait ERP {
    fn new() -> Self;
    fn sample(&self) -> f64;
}

pub struct Bernoulli {
    p: f64
}

impl ERP for Bernoulli {
    fun new(p: f64) -> Bernoulli {
        Bernoulli { p: p }
    }

    fun sample(&self) -> f64 { self.p } // Filler code
}

pub struct Gaussian {
    mu: f64,
    sigma: f64
}

impl ERP for Gaussian {
    fun new(mu: f64, sigma: f64) -> Gaussian {
        Gaussian { mu: mu, sigma: sigma }
    }

    fun sample(&self) -> f64 { self.mu } // Filler code
}
```

But of course I get

```
error: method new` has 1 parameter but the declaration in trait
`erp::ERP::new` has 0
```

since I must specify a fixed number of arguments in the trait.

I also can't leave `new` out of the trait, since that gives

```
error: method `new` is not a member of trait `ERP`
```

My motivation is that I want the exposed ERP interface to stay consistent *except* for the `new` method, since each distribution's required parameters are dependent on the unique mathematics behind its implementation. Are there any workarounds?

Comment: Please read the rust-book. You can implement functions directly on types: https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/book/method-syntax.html and your previous question would have been answered by the trait chapter in the rust-book https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/book/traits.html#default-methods

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Don't make the `new` function part of the trait. Functions with variable number of input arguments are not supported.

Comment: I then get the error "method `new` is not a member of trait `ERP`".

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize you can implement both the type directly and a trait for the type. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @a-b , I think that you can have the `new` static method in traits now: https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/trait.html