# Extracting varying, parameterized 'new' methods to trait

Tags: rust, methods, struct, traits

I'm new to Rust and just bumped into this issue.

I have many different structs, that all implement their own `new` methods, with a varying number of input parameters and types. Every new method does something like this:

```
impl MyStruct {
    pub fn new(param1: String, param2: u32, param3: char) -> Self {
        MyStruct {
            id: None,
            param1,
            param2,
            param3,
        }
    }
}
```

Every struct that implements this `new` method has the same general structure, with varying types and amounts of fields:

```
pub struct MyStruct {
    pub id: Option<i64>,
    pub param1: String,
    pub param2: u32,
    pub param3: char,
    // more params
}
```

Manually implementing the `new` method on every struct seems like a lot of code repetition. Is there some way to extract this functionality into a trait?

I initially thought of using enums or generics as the parameters of the `new` method in the trait, but couldn't come up with a concrete solution.

Comment: See also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31187986/20665825

Comment: @JonasFassbender That derive-new crate you mentioned looks really good! I think it perfectly solves my problem. Thanks :)

Comment: rust-analyzer has an assist "generate new function".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the different signatures, you won't be able to use a trait for this. Same with enums and generics. There is the [derive-new](https://docs.rs/derive-new/latest/derive_new/) crate you could use if your `new` associated functions are simple and don't require any computation done in them.

Comment: Instead of posting on this (imo duplicate) question it would be better to add to the duplicate target you found, if not already answered there, that way we keep the information in one place, making the answers easier to find.